# How do I install a phonegap plugin when using Eclipse?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a phonegap application in Eclipse and would like to install a plugin.

I'm trying to install this barcode scanner plugin:
http://phonegap.com/blog/build/barcodescanner-plugin/

However, all instructions are for the command line and I am using eclipse.  I can't figure out which directory to be in when I install the plugin.

I also tried 'phonegap local plugin list' to get a list of plugins.  I get the error "project directory could not be found".

Which directory should I be in the install a plugin?

I think this project was originally created with the command line but then imported into Eclipse.  In Eclipse the structure looks different.
The CordovaLib project appears as an second project the same level with my project.  At the command line it was nested in a subfolder under my project.
I also don't see a .cordova folder.

After the project was imported into eclipse it was added to TFS.  The version I have came from TFS and it seems some of the folder structure was not in TFS (only things reference by the project).  However, everything works and I can also build it with phonegap build.

Comment: I would suggest using the cli for building phonegap projects. Its much much easier and imo better for several reasons over using eclipse. You can then edit your files in a simple text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download manually your plugins from the Git Hub repository into your main project. Additionally config xml has to be modified in make cordova aware of the new plug-in.